# Regex with Named Capture Group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to update a regex pattern to include a `Named Capture Group`. Currently, this regex pattern:

`\b\d(?!(?:\d{0,3}([-\/\\.])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4})\b(?!\S))(?:[^\n\d\$\.\%]*\d){14}\b`

correctly returns **4 matches** from this sample text:

```
AAA
43 42 040 012 036 00
43 42 090 037 124 00
53 07 010 005 124 00
06-14 301-830-081-49
BBB
```

When I revised the pattern to add a `Named Capture Group` it only returns **3 matches** and misses the last one.

`(?<myPattern>\b\d(?!(?:\d{0,3}([-\/\\.])\d{1,2}\1\d{1,4})\b(?!\S))(?:[^\n\d\$\.\%]*\d){14}\b)`

How can I keep the `Named Capture Group` but still return **4 matches** ?

See example [here](https://regexr.com/716ma).

Thanks.

Comment: Because the named group is Group 1, `\1`. Replace `\1` with `\2`.

Comment: Thank you.  If you post as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named [capturing groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences#types) are still assigned numeric IDs. That is, `(?<myPattern>[a-z]+)(\d+)` contains two groups, the first one - with ID 1 - is "myPattern" group matching one or more lowercase letters, and the second group is `\d+`, with ID 2.

In your case, the problem arises due to the use of the `\1` backreference later in the pattern. It refers to "myPattern" group value now, so the matching is incorrect.

To fix the issue, you need to replace `\1` to the corresponding group, `\2`:

```
(?<myPattern>\b\d(?!(?:\d{0,3}([-\/\\.])\d{1,2}\2\d{1,4})\b(?!\S))(?:[^\n\d\$\.\%]*\d){14}\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regexr.com/716mv).